# Git equivalent for “hg log” with branch name check

Tags: git, mercurial, tortoisehg

I would like to list down all commits directly done in a particular branch. In hg I'm able to get it using the below command.

```
hg log -b {branchname}
```

I've tried different command git to achieve the same but, nothing is useful.

```
git log --no-merges
git log --no-merges --first-parent
git log ---no-merge ^HEAD ^master
git log --branches={BRANCH}
```

**How to list all changesets that are directly committed in a given branch** but, not merges from other branches.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), you should be able to use `--no-merges` in git as well. If that is not "useful" for you, you will have to give examples of why, and what output you expect.

Comment: What a branch is moved? What if those commits weren’t “committed under” a branch but now they show up.

Comment: I don't think you will have the exactly same feature as a commit is not linked to a branch like it is done in Mercurial (for the few I know). In Git, branch (or more generally refs) are pointers toward a commit.

Comment: What specifically is wrong with `git log --first-parent --no-merges`? That's lists no merges and no merged history for the branch you start with, as far back as you want.

Comment: What @Philippe said is correct: in Mercurial, branches really matter. They are a first-class entity and the branch names are shared between different repositories. This is not the case in Git: a Git commit does not record its branch, and branch names are not shared the same way. (One Git repository can *see* the other's branch names, but is not obligated to *use* them. It's true that with Hg's "convert" extension, you can map branch names across Hg's repositories, but there's still a first-class notion of "branch name" attached to each commit.)

Comment: if someone merges their branch with master then those commit are getting listed in all branches. I want to omit those changesets also. I just want to changesets/commits done directly in that branch

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is a fundamental difference between git and mercurial :

Mercurial has several kind of objects, among which : branches, and bookmarks.
`git` branches are like `hg` bookmarks, not like `hg` branches.

You will always only be able to see the history of the head commit of a git branch, not the actual sequence of intermediate states it went through.

---

It looks like you already tried the things that are close to "the history of a branch", I would have suggested :

```
git log --first-parent
```

`git` also keeps a log of how your local branch evolved through :

```
 git reflog <branchname>
```

but this log may be flushed if your branch was renamed at some point.

You can also have a partial view of how a remote branch evolved :

```
git reflog origin/<branchname>
```

this log is updated only when you `fetch` (or `pull`), so you may miss several intermediate steps if the branch was updated several times by other people between two `fetch`.

---

If you want to see commits on `branch` which are not part of `master`, try :

```
git log master..branch
# which is the same as :
git log ^master branch
```

Comment: git log --first-parent

if someone merges their branch with master then those commit are getting listed in all branches. I want to omit those changesets also. I just want to changesets/commits done directly in that branch

Comment: In your question, you said you already tried `git log --no-merges --first-parent` ; what doesn't fit your expectations with this command ?

Comment: I've created a test branch few weeks back and did only one commit. My expectation is to get that changeset alone but, with git log --no-merges --first-parent it is giving multiple changesets which were came from other branches while merging with master.

Comment: Did you try `git log master..HEAD` or `git log master..branch` ? If your branch is not merged into master yet, this should be enough. For merged branch you need an extra step.